# Spring Neo4j batch over REST

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4j in standalone mode with Spring Data for Neo4j in my application. My code needs to be able ensure that when I try to save a object, either everything goes in or nothing does. I know that transactions are not supported over REST in Spring Neo4j, but the [batch operation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html)  in Neo4j's REST API should be fine for my current needs. There aren't that many operations, but the whole save() call needs to be a all-or-nothing thing.

However, it appears that Spring doesn't do this by default. If you have a RuntimeException occur during the write, there will still be some partial data put in the database. I would like to continue using GraphRepository interface, but if this isn't possible I suppose I could manually implement this.

Here's some simplified example code to illustrate what happens

**POJO**:

```
@NodeEntity
public class TestObject {
  @GraphId
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  @Fetch
  @RelatedTo(type = "SIBLING_OF", direction = Direction.BOTH)
  private Set<TestObject> siblings;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    if (name == "fail") {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Set<TestObject> getSiblings() {
    return siblings;
  }

  public void setSiblings(Set<TestObject> siblings) {
    this.siblings = siblings;
  }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface TestRepository extends GraphRepository<TestObject>{}
```

**Test**

```
public class Test {
  @Autowired
  TestRepository repo;

  public void run() {
    final TestObject o1 = new TestObject();
    o1.setName("good1");

    final TestObject o2 = new TestObject();
    o1.setName("good2");

    final TestObject o3 = new TestObject();
    o1.setName("good3");

    final TestObject o4 = new TestObject();
    o1.setName("fail");

    o1.setSiblings(new HashSet<TestObject>() {{
      add(o2);
      add(o3);
      add(o4);
    }});

    //throws exception, but o1 node is created in Neo4j
    repo.save(o1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    Test t = (Test) appContext.getBean("test");
    t.run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDN doesn't really support the "fake" transactions that the batch-API represents over the wire as it uses read after write and that doesn't work.

For now I'd rather recommend that you either run SDN with an embedded DB or you write a server extension using SDN and exposing a custom REST endpoint.

Comment: I'd prefer not to go the embedded route. Do you have a link to some examples of server extensions in SDN?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to reuse the code SDN uses to generate node JSON from a POJO? I could fairly easily implement my own saveInBatch() method using the vanilla REST API if I could take advantage of something SDN already does.